# cakephp null value on condition

Tags: cakephp

```
 $this->paginate['Member'] = array(
        'conditions' => array($conditions,'Member.division_id' => $currentTeam['Division']['id'],'Member.team_id'=> array(null,0)),
        'group' => 'Member.id',

    );
```

This query does not get the NULL team id.. It gets just the team id 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$this->paginate['Member'] = [
    'conditions' => [
        $conditions,
        'Member.division_id' => $currentTeam['Division']['id'],
        'OR' => [
            ['team_id' => null],
            ['team_id' => 0],
        ],
        'group' => 'Member.id',
    ];
```

Wrapped each `team_id` condition in it's own array. This prevents the issue of a duplicated `team_id` array key, while still using a consistent format for the conditions.

Comment: How can this be a correct answer? the OR array has duplicate key 'team_id' so the value is always 0 only, null will be lost

Comment: Someone fixed it now, it seems.

Answer (score 12):

Using the IS NULL keyword usually works.

```
array( 
    $conditions,
    'Member.division_id' => $currentTeam['Division']['id'],
    'OR' => array(
        'Member.team_id' => 0,
        'Member.team_id IS NULL'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
array( 
   $conditions,
   'Member.division_id' => $currentTeam['Division']['id'],
     'OR' => array(
        'Member.team_id' => 0,
        'IS' => array( 'Member.team_id' => NULL )
     )
 )
```

This is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->paginate['Member'] = array(
        'conditions' => array($conditions,
                'Member.division_id' => $currentTeam['Division']['id'],
                'OR'=> array('Member.team_id'=> null, 'Member.team_id'=> 0),
                'group' => 'Member.id',

);
```